# Check if strings in column matches one of two formats, if not re-format the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column of strings which are IDs that are suppose to follow the format of either: C-xxxxx-U-## or C-xxxxx-UX-## where x can be a digit or a uppercase letter.

I want to check that the ID follows either of these formats and if it doesn't I want to re-format the string so it does.

Some example data:

```
C-20BV7-U-00
C-20BW5-U-00
C1AWT4-UR-00  <--- wrong format
C-1B8V9-UR-00
C-20BX2-U-00
```

I think this will give me the rows that don't follow that format

```
result=df["ID"].str.match(pat='C-[A-Z0-9]{5}-U[A-Z0-9]{0,1}-[0-9]{2}$')
temp=df.loc[~result,"ID"]
```

but how I do change the format to what I want without specific replace since I don't know exactly how it will differ from the format

Comment: what should the format be to replace it?

Comment: Is this `C1AWT4-UR-00` the only wrong format? Show other variations is that could be a case

Comment: either C-xxxxx-U-## or C-xxxxx-UX-## where x can be a digit or a uppercase letter. Basically its data that was user inputted and I want to check if there are any values that were inputted wrong

Comment: if problem can be only with hyphen - remove all but digits and letters and set hyphens by self

Comment: While i understand your issue, my only comment is the cleanest way to handle this would be to validate and reject the user input if it doesnt match the format, rather than accept anything and have to try to format it later

Comment: Right. But I don't have any control over that. This isn't data I collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With specific regex replacement:

```
In [51]: df['ID'].str.replace(r'^C([^-])', 'C-\\1').replace(r'-U[^A-Z0-9]+', '-U')                           
Out[51]: 
0     C-20BV7-U-00
1     C-20BW5-U-00
2    C-1AWT4-UR-00
3    C-1B8V9-UR-00
4     C-20BX2-U-00
Name: ID, dtype: object
```